# Unable to access ASP.NET Core app from alpine docker container after updating to .NET 8

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I have my ASP.NET Core 7.0 app running in AWS Elastic Container Service using container built from the alpine image using the following Docker file.

ASP.NET Core 7.0 Docker File:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib  
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["IDP/IDP.csproj", "IDP/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["Shared/Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "IDP/IDP.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/IDP"
RUN dotnet build "IDP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IDP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IDP.dll"]
```

Now after updating to .NET 8, I can see that container is still running but not able to access any endpoints from my app.

Then after googling, I came across the following breaking changes document.

Default Port Mapping Change:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port

So I added the following in my Docker File:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib  
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80     #<---- Newly added
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=443   #<---- Newly added
EXPOSE 80                        #<---- Newly added
EXPOSE 443
```

Then I started to get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
```

Now the container is not running and started to throw certificate error.

Again found another breaking change related certificate document as per below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/krb5-libs-package

Docker File:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib ca-certificates  #<---- Newly added ca-certificates
```

Still facing the same error.

Here is my final ASP.NET Core 8 Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib ca-certificates 
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=443
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["IDP/IDP.csproj", "IDP/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["Shared/Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "IDP/IDP.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/IDP"
RUN dotnet build "IDP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IDP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IDP.dll"]
```

Please can anyone help me on what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you actually using 443 port of the container?

Comment: I think its not. That's the learning for me from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to version 8, your container listened on port 80.

To get it back to doing that, it's enough to add

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80
```

to your Dockerfile.

When you add `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS` as well, your app wants to listen for HTTPS traffic. It didn't do that before, even though you `EXPOSE` port 443. EXPOSE is mainly documentation and your case, it's not correct.
When your app starts listening for HTTPS traffic, it needs a certificate which you haven't provided. That's why it fails.

Try this as your Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib ca-certificates 
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["IDP/IDP.csproj", "IDP/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["Shared/Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "IDP/IDP.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/IDP"
RUN dotnet build "IDP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IDP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IDP.dll"]
```

That should make your app behave like it did before.

Comment: That worked. Many thanks for support and explanation.